# N-th Root Calculation extremly slow in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm using DrRacket for my Programming Class. With a simplified syntax I think.
The exercise is to calculate the nth-root of a given number with a given precision. 
This program works fine but If it try to use it with the 5-th root of 243 (which is 3), the program is too slow to calculate it. However if stack up the `(improve 1 5 243)`function, it works. But if I stack it more often than 7 times, the program execution takes too long.

What is the problem?

Here is the program: (it uses the Newton-algorithm)

```
(check-within (nth-root 3 125 0.001) 5 0.001)
(check-within (nth-root 2 625 0.01) 25 0.01)
(check-within (nth-root 3 64 0.001) 4 0.001)
(: nth-root (natural natural real -> real))
(define nth-root
  (lambda (n x eps) (root-iter 1 1 n x eps)))

(: root-iter (real real natural natural real -> real))
(define root-iter
  (lambda (current last n x eps)
    (if (good-enough? current n x eps)
        current
        (root-iter (improve last n x) current n x eps))))

(: improve (real natural natural -> real))
(define improve
   (lambda (last n x)
    (* (/ 1 n)
       (+ (/ x
              (expt last (- n 1)))
          (* (- n 1)
              last)))))

(: good-enough? (real natural natural real -> boolean))
(define good-enough?
   (lambda (current n x eps)
    (< (abs (- (expt current n) x)) eps)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly the case that you're using exact arithmetic here. That's going to be costly in this particular situation because your math will be all in rational numbers; your numerators and denominators are going to get HUGE. Get into inexact arithmetic, and you should see a major performance improvement (at the cost of precision, mind you).

Racket (and Scheme in general) gives you exact arithmetic if you're dealing with exact numbers.  And it turns out that the way that you've improving your guess from iteration to iteration all use exact numbers!  :P

To confirm the effect of this, try: `(nth-root 5 243.0 0.001)`. Compare vs `(nth-root 5 243 0.001)`, and you should see a big difference in the amount of time it takes to compute the answer.

That's why you'll see functions like `exact->inexact` in Scheme.  And why you'll see floating-point (inexact) arithmetic in your computer: you will run into situations where getting the Platonic answer is prohibitively expensive, and for many applications, you can tolerate the inexactness.

(Though not in finance.  Do not use inexact numbers when you're dealing with money, or you will make someone very, very unhappy.)